# Repository pattern and stored procedure

Tags: .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, repository-pattern

I am looking for a good example projects for using repository pattern and stored procedure.  I have spent a lot of times,I can't find any good example that use sp to commmunicate with repository pattern and db.  Even a regular CRUD, I will still use SP.

Also, does anyone have an example to do complex data in stored procedure to code in EF?
For example, stored procedure return multiple data tables?
Thanks

Comment: There are tons of examples over on the google machine demonstrating the repository pattern. Also, you are asking a second question that isn't really clear ...what do you mean by *do complex data in stored procedure to code in EF*

Comment: I can't find any good example that use sp to commmunicate with repository pattern.  Even a regular CRUD, I will still use SP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't find any good example that use sp to commmunicate with
>   repository pattern. Even a regular CRUD, I will still use SP.

Just think about the [pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) and your options - you can use only SPs and you want object responsible for data access. You don't need any example project - you just need to think.

When implementing repository with stored procedures you will end with simple DAO (data access object) defined by interface like:

```
public interface IEntityDao
{
    IEnumerable<Entity> GetAll();
    Entity GetByKey(int key);
    bool Insert(Entity data);
    bool Update(Entity data);
    bool Delete(int key);
}
```

This is basic interface for CRUD operations on `Entity` persisted class. Every method implementation will call single stored procedure to perform the operation. If you will need any other operation (for example some filtering or ordering) you will create new stored procedure and expose new operation calling this stored procedure.

There can be discussion if this is or is not repository but simply SPs will not offer you anything more. For example this part of definition is mostly impossible to achieve on generic level:

> Client objects construct query specifications declaratively and submit
>   them to Repository for satisfaction.

Your "query specification" will always be only parameters specific to given stored procedure and passed to your exposed operation. You will not be able to declaratively define whole query (unless you pass SQL as parameter to your SP).

You can call stored procedures directly by ADO.NET or use either function imports or `ExecuteStoreQuery` / `ExecuteStoreCommand` in EF. EF is able to execute complex stored procedures with this limitations:

- stored procedure returns only single result set. For multiple result sets you will need either [EFExtensions](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions) or you will have to wait for .NET 4.5 where this feature should be included
- stored procedure must not return different result set - it means that structure of result set must be the same for each SP execution (no pivots or dynamic SQL returning different number of columns)

Function imports have few more minor limitations. If you follow these rules you will be able to create classes / complex types for every result set returned by your SP.

Comment: Alright, It means I shouldn't use from Repository according to your recommendation. Isn't it?  
I am so confuse and how to use the EF for entity mapping.  That's why I really want an example.

Comment: I didn't say that. If you need to use SPs you will always end with something like this.

Comment: I edited my previous answer.
Because the way you describe is simply ADO.Net which is my current project design with CRUD.

Comment: If you already have implementation with direct ADO.NET you will not get too much benefit by moving to EF.